# How do I change layoutAttributes in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and I want to change the layoutAttributes of my collectionView.

I am calling this function:

```
    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    print("Layout has been changed lit fool.")
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 40)
    layoutAttributes.frame.size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
}
```

For some reason my layoutAttributes are not being effected by this code. No matter what variable I change my targetSize to, the collectionView size stays the same. The print statement is running, so I know that this function is getting called correctly, its just the layoutAttributes don't change.

How do I get my layoutAttributes to change from this function?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: Check this out for the problem I am trying to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320752/uicollectionviewcell-improperly-sizes-itself-after-calling-reloaddata.

Comment: I think you should create custom UICollectionViewLayout or UICollectionViewFlowLayout which one are you using. Inside view layout you can easily cache and apply it to layout attributes.